# How to download and install Heroku?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wget, heroku

I downloaded Heroku from Heroku toolbelt using

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

in the terminal, which they recommended on their site.   My Ubuntu (14.04.1) didn't recognize the `-q0-`, so I took it out.  It then seemed to download fine - I see the  in the directory I was in when i downloaded it.

Now, however, it still doesn't recognize `heroku` as a command.  It also won't show me where it is with the 'whereis' command.  But when I look in the current directory with `ls -a`, it shows up.  It seems to be there.

How do I install it?

Comment: it looks like heroku toolbelt is on apt:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/15203840/262852  ??? Or not?  I don't see it...no ppa.

Answer (score 26):

Just tried this now on 14.04. Here is how I did it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Once it finished installing, I typed `heroku apps`.  see image below for more info.

[image]

Comment: You might receive the following warning: "WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  heroku heroku-toolbelt
" . Then just run "apt-get install -y --force-yes heroku-toolbelt"

Answer (score 11):

You can install Heroku on Ubuntu 14.04 or any later version as a snap:

```
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

[This is published directly by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#ubuntu-snap). It updates automatically whenever they release a new version.

The more adventurous can install from the edge channel and get updates for every upstream commit:

```
sudo snap install --classic --edge heroku
```

Comment: make sure `/snap/bin` is in `$PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Configuring Heroku is quite straight-forward on DigitalOcean. After ssh-ing, run the following commands with sudo:

```
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-x64.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz
tar -xvzf heroku.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin
```

List the content of the current directory with `ls`. I found this output:

```
heroku-cli-v6.15.22-3f1c4bd-linux-x64  
heroku.tar.gz
```

This output determines the value in the next step, use the first file name in the next command:

```
sudo mv heroku-cli-v6.15.22-3f1c4bd-linux-x64 /usr/local/lib/heroku
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
```

And that's it.

Comment: These helped with setting up on WSL! Thanks :D

Comment: @pai.not.pi I'm extremely glad to be helpful :)