# Installing heroku CLI: 404 Not Found

Tags: software-installation

```
$ wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
$ wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels  /stable/heroku-cli-REPLACEME_OS-REPLACE_ME_ARCH.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz
--2017-08-24 02:13:33--  https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels /stable/heroku-cli-REPLACEME_OS-REPLACE_ME_ARCH.tar.gz
Resolving cli-assets.heroku.com (cli-assets.heroku.com)... 54.192.209.81,54.192.209.52, 54.192.209.134, ...
Connecting to cli-assets.heroku.com (cli-assets.heroku.com)|54.192.209.81|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-08-24 02:13:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

How about this?

```
$ mv heroku-cli-v6.x.x-darwin-64 /usr/local/lib/heroku
mv: cannot stat ‘heroku-cli-v6.x.x-darwin-64’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/556685/how-to-download-and-install-heroku

Comment: askubuntu.com/questions/556685/… – @Terrance, its still the same error/problem

Comment: Did you look at the linked question there?  It might help you install Heroku.  Looks like the location for the wget you have here is invalid.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#debian-ubuntu 
can you look at this link.... it is Download & Install Heroku Command Line Interface to use for heroku & Django deployment in Python and it is my first time to use Ubuntu.... Thank you for helping, i appreciate it..

Comment: Wrote an answer for you based on the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you provided to download, you need to replace the `REPLACE_ME_OS/REPLACE_ME_ARCH` with the appropriate information.  Below that section you will find the following notes:

> Where REPLACE_ME_OS is one of “linux”, “darwin”, “windows” and
> REPLACE_ME_ARCH is one of “x64” or “x86” You also must replace “6.x.x”
> with the actual version.

So, your download with the `wget` would look like the following, assuming that you are running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu:

```
wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-x64.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz
```

Then all you should have to do is to continue the steps below:

```
tar -xvzf heroku.tar.gz

mkdir -p /usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin

mv heroku-cli-v6.13.19-6cd27b3-linux-x64 /usr/local/lib/heroku

ln -s /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku /usr/local/bin/heroku
```

Hope this helps!

[edited second argument to `mv` from `bin` to `lib` - site does not allow a 3 letter change, hence this comment!]

Comment: mv: cannot stat ‘heroku-cli-v6.x.x-darwin-64’: No such file or directory

Comment: @junel I updated my answer for you.  That file does not exist.  That was part of the instructions from their site if you had a Mac.